# tf timing problem when using STAGE simulation

Tags: ros, simulation, simulator-stage, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm currently trying to simulate the behavior of my robot using STAGE simulation but the tf timing from STAGE is too slow with a time interval of 13 x10^6 second. I tried to overcome this problem by overwrite the tf using the static transform publisher but the time become negative with this warning:

TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame /base_footprint at time 12.6 according to authority /Stage_Node

How should i approach this problem?

With thanks,
Zhiping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9424/tf-timing-problem-when-using-stage-simulation/) by [zhiping](https://answers.ros.org/users/131/zhiping/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2011-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhiping](https://answers.ros.org/users/131/zhiping/) on 2011-03-15**:
I'm trying to link the STAGE, move_base and gmapping together in order to simulate a online SLAM. The TF link is /map (slam_gmapping) >> /odom (Stage_node)>>/base_footprint (Stage_node) >> /base_link (Stage_node) >> /base_laser_link (Stage_node)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-15**:
Can you be a little more specific about your setup.  In general Stage works fine with tf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With that big of an error, make sure to set /use_sim_time properly before starting all processes.  See the [Clock](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock) documentation.

---

Originally posted by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) with karma: 1145 on 2011-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhiping](https://answers.ros.org/users/131/zhiping/) on 2011-03-15**:
Thank a lot. Using simulation time does solve the problem.